# Combine multiple dataframes by summing certain columns in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sum

Given three dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [5, 0], 'B': [2, 4], 'C': 'dog'})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1], 'B': [3, 3], 'C': 'dog'})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2, 1], 'B': [5, 1], 'C': 'dog'})
```

how can one combine them into a single dataframe, by adding the values of a subset of given dataframes, such that the result becomes:

```
pd.DataFrame({'A': [8, 2], 'B': [10, 8], 'C': 'dog'})
```

for this example? My problem is that I also have columns which are identical, but cannot be summed (like `'C'` here).

Comment: are there only 3 dfs or more?

Comment: in my case only 3

Comment: Also what happens if col C has different data in 3 dfs

Comment: In the case of same value its not problematic. But what is the decision if one is dog and one is cat?

Comment: then we put ['dog', 'cat'] in a list, on that row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution with `sum` if numeric values and if strings then join unique values per groups in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) after [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) list of `DataFrame`s:

```
f = lambda x: x.sum() if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else ','.join(x.unique())
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], keys=range(3)).groupby(level=1).agg(f)
print (df)
   A   B    C
0  8  10  dog
1  2   8  dog
```

If possible different values like `cat` and `dog`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [5, 0], 'B': [2, 4], 'C': 'dog'})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1], 'B': [3, 3], 'C': 'dog'})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2, 1], 'B': [5, 1], 'C': ['cat','dog']})


f = lambda x: x.sum() if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else ','.join(x.unique())
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], keys=range(3)).groupby(level=1).agg(f)
print (df)
   A   B        C
0  8  10  dog,cat
1  2   8      dog
```

If need lists:

```
f = lambda x: x.sum() if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else x.unique().tolist()
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], keys=range(3)).groupby(level=1).agg(f)
print (df)
   A   B           C
0  8  10  [dog, cat]
1  2   8       [dog]
```

And for combination lists with scalars for nonnumeric values use custom function:

```
def f(x):
    if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number):
        return x.sum()
    else:
        u = x.unique().tolist()
        if len(u) == 1:
            return u[0]
        else:
            return u

df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], keys=range(3)).groupby(level=1).agg(f)
print (df)
   A   B           C
0  8  10  [dog, cat]
1  2   8         dog
```

Comment: I applied it to my real dataframes and from 3 dataframes of 5 rows × 67 columns, I get one with 5 rows × 700 columns, why does this happen?

Comment: @Qubix - columns names are different in each DataFrame?

Comment: you are right, they are. So can I assume that the last block of code above sums-up the columns that are common and leaves the ones that are not common with the same value they had in their original dataframe?

Comment: @Qubix - hmmm, `concat` join together, but if different columns then no alignment data (need same columns in each for create one column after concat with same name and filled by data from each df1, df2, df3). So the best here is try normalize and unify columns names for same in each df1, df2, df3

Answer (score 0):

you can do it as follows:

```
df = df3.copy()
df[['A','B']] = df1[['A','B']]+df2[['A','B']]+df3[['A','B']]
```

gives the following output, if you want you can:

```
:df

    A   B   C
0   8   10  dog
1   2   8   dog
```